# iOS, pull certain parts from ugly web page source code

Tags: html, ios, regex

I need to pull text from a web page source code, but the html is ugly with mainly tr and td tag elements.

For instance, in the second tr element I would want the text '80 Sand Bass, 10 Barracuda, 1 Bonito, 15 Rockfish'.  In the third tr element I would want the text '55 Calico Bass, 30 Barracuda, 8 Bonito, 15 Rockfish'

What would be the best way for me to pull certain parts from source code in this situation.
I can't use stringByEvaluatingJavaScriptFromString because of the lack of keyword id's.

The following code returns a string with the complete contents of the page but how would I search for the line I want.

```
NSString *hmlanding = @"http://www.hmlanding.com/fcount/fcount.htm";

NSURL *hmlandingURL = [NSURL hmlanding];
NSError *error;
NSString *hmlandingPage = [NSString stringWithContentsOfURL:hmlandingURL 
                                                encoding:NSASCIIStringEncoding
                                                   error:&error];
```

//part of the ugly html source code

```
<tr>

    <td align="center" valign="top" bgcolor="#CCCCFF" height="38" width="202">
    <b><A HREF="fcount_malihini.htm" target="_blank">Malihini<font size="2">
</font> 
    </A><font size="2">&nbsp;(Mexico freelance)</font><BR>
<A HREF="http://www.malihinisportfishing.com/report.html" target="_blank">
<FONT SIZE="-1"><I>On the Water Report</I></FONT> </A>&nbsp;</b></td>
    <td align="center" valign="top" bgcolor="#CCCCFF" height="38" width="61">
    44</td>
    <td align="center" valign="top" bgcolor="#CCCCFF" height="38" width="435">
    121 Yellowtail, 1 Dorado, 3 Yellowfin Tuna</td>
</tr>
<tr>
    <td align="center" valign="top" bgcolor="#CCCCFF" height="19" width="202">
    <strong><A HREF="fcount_premier.htm" target="_blank">Premier<span style="text-decoration: none"> 
    AM<font size="2" color="#000000">
    </font></span></A></strong></td>
    <td align="center" valign="top" bgcolor="#CCCCFF" height="19" width="61">
    59</td>
    <td align="center" valign="top" bgcolor="#CCCCFF" height="19" width="435">
    80 Sand Bass, 10 Barracuda, 1 Bonito, 15 Rockfish</td>
</tr>
<tr>
    <td align="center" valign="top" bgcolor="#CCCCFF" height="19" width="202">
    <strong>
    <u>
    <font color="#0000CC"><A HREF="fcount_premier.htm" target="_blank">
    Premier</a></font><font color="#0000FF"><span style="text-decoration: none">
    PM</span></font></u></strong></td>
    <td align="center" valign="top" bgcolor="#CCCCFF" height="19" width="61">
    29</td>
    <td align="center" valign="top" bgcolor="#CCCCFF" height="19" width="435">
    55 Calico Bass, 30 Barracuda, 8 Bonito, 15 Rockfish</td>
</tr>
    <tr>
    <td bgcolor="#CCCCFF">
    <p align="center"><b><font color="#0000CC"><u>Premier Twilight </u>
<font size="2">&nbsp;</font></font></b></td>
    <td bgcolor="#CCCCFF">
    <p align="center">&nbsp;</td>
    <td align="center" bgcolor="#CCCCFF" height="20" width="435">&nbsp;</td>
</tr>
```

Comment: Use an HTML-Parser. I like [TFHpple](https://github.com/topfunky/hpple) very much.

Comment: +1 For `TFHpple`. I imagine a short, round penguin running through XML and picking up important pieces for me.